# Array is getting corrupted in between function calls

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to implement stack data structure using array. When I am calling the push() function for the first time it works fine. But when I am calling it for the second time I am getting segmentation fault at the statement:- `*stack[*tos] = data;`

May be the reason behind this is that the array is getting corrupted. I discovered this reason when I executed the pop() function. It is altering all the elements except the one that is being popped. I am assigning '0' to the popped element.

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void push(int data, int *tos, int size, int **stack)
{
    (*tos)++;
    printf("\ntos = %d\n", *tos);
    if (*tos > size)
    {
        puts("\nStack Overflow!!!\n");
        (*tos)--;
        return;
    }
    printf("\ndata = %d\n", data);
    *stack[*tos] = data;
    printf("\nstack[*tos] = %d\n", *stack[*tos]);
}

void pop(int *tos, int **stack)
{
    if ((*tos) == -1)
    {
        puts("\nStack Underflow!!!\n");
        return;
    }
    stack[*tos] = 0;
    (*tos)--;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d\t", stack[i]);
    puts("\n");

}

int main()
{
    int size = 0, tos = -1;
    printf("\nEnter size of stack: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int *stack = (int *) calloc(size, sizeof(int));

    push(9, &tos, size, &stack); push(1, &tos, size, &stack); //push(2, &tos, size, stack); push(3, &tos, size, stack); push(4, &tos, size, stack);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d\t", stack[i]);
    puts("\n");

    pop(&tos, &stack); //pop(&tos, &stack);

    /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d\t", stack[i]);
    puts("\n");*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your program.

Comment: `printf("%d\t", stack[i]);` you deckared stack as `int **stack`

Comment: `calloc(size, sizeof(int));` here size should be `size_t`.

Comment: @Michi Thanks for the tips and all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the indirection operator `*`. So

```
*stack[*tos] = data;
```

is parsed as:

```
*(stack[*tos]) = data;
```

But `stack` is a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers, so you need to indirect through it first, before subscripting. So it should be:

```
(*stack)[*tos] = data;
```

And `pop()` is missing all the dereferences of `stack`.

Here's the fully working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void push(int data, int *tos, int size, int **stack)
{
    (*tos)++;
    printf("\ntos = %d\n", *tos);
    if (*tos > size)
    {
        puts("\nStack Overflow!!!\n");
        (*tos)--;
        return;
    }
    printf("\ndata = %d\n", data);
    (*stack)[*tos] = data;
    printf("\nstack[*tos] = %d\n", (*stack)[*tos]);
}

void pop(int *tos, int **stack)
{
    if ((*tos) == -1)
    {
        puts("\nStack Underflow!!!\n");
        return;
    }
    (*stack)[*tos] = 0;
    (*tos)--;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (*tos); i++)
        printf("%d\t", (*stack)[i]);
    puts("\n");

}

int main()
{
    int size = 0, tos = -1;
    printf("\nEnter size of stack: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int *stack = (int *) calloc(size, sizeof(int));

    push(9, &tos, size, &stack);
    push(1, &tos, size, &stack);
    push(2, &tos, size, &stack);
    push(3, &tos, size, &stack);
    push(4, &tos, size, &stack);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d\t", stack[i]);
    puts("\n");

    pop(&tos, &stack); //pop(&tos, &stack);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d\t", stack[i]);
    puts("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: segfault will still occurs and of course OP's code has multiple problems.